# Why is my neural network giving unequal probabilities when predicting an image that isn't one of the given classes?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras

Let's say I had 5 different types of images I wanted to classify in my neural network and I trained it on 10,000 images. When it is done training, I give it an image that it has never seen before and isn't part of one of the 5 classes. Shouldn't it give a semi-equal probability distribution of what class it is. Something like [0.20, 0.20, 0.20. 0.20, 0.20]. Instead my model in Keras predicts that it is certain it is one of the 5 even though it isn't one of the classes. Ex. [.99, 0, 0, 0, .01]. Is this a result of over training or something similar?

Comment: Suppose you had 2 classes: dog and airplane. A cat looks more like a dog than it does an airplane. Would you expect the network to give equal probabilities to a cat? Why? What attributes of a cat make it equally plausible as a dog or an airplane?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not overfitting but overconfidence, which is a common property of normal CNNs. Bayesian CNNs and models that include uncertainty quantification would give you something closer to the effect you want, with increased entropy in the output probabilities for out-of-distribution examples.

For this problem you can take a look at two papers:

- [A Baseline for Detecting Misclassified and Out of Distribution Examples in Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02136).
- [Simple and Scalable Predictive Uncertainty Estimation using Deep Ensembles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474).